# "Invalid read syntax: . in wrong context"

Tags: init-file, debugging

I wanted to add a new display setting to init.el file, but didn't like it and removed the line. Now when I start emacs I get this error:

Invalid read syntax: . in wrong context

Here is the init.el file:

```
((require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/" t)))
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages '(solarized-theme)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
)
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)
(custom-set-variables
  '(default-frame-alist
      '((background-color . "#1b1c1f")
        (background-mode . dark))))
(global-set-key (kbd "<home>") 'move-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "<end>") 'move-end-of-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "<Control>space") 'set-mark-command)
```

I am not familiar with lisp. Is there a typo here? Debug-init mode gives me the below:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ". in wrong context")
read(#<buffer  *load*>)
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/admin/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t) ; 
Reading at buffer position 103
load-with-code-conversion("/Users/admin/.emacs.d/init.el" 
"/Users/ozandernek/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
load("/Users/ozandernek/.emacs.d/init" noerror nomessage)
startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4e46592b>) 
#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4e465941>) t)
command-line()
normal-top-level()
```

Comment: The `t` at the end of the second line is wrong: delete it. It was trying to read a dotted pair `("melpa" . "https://etc")` and it found a `t` where it expected a closing paren. Since dotted pairs are relatively rare, it chose to believe that you were trying to enter a list `("melpa" "https://etc" t)` but it guessed wrong (I guess :-) )

Comment: @NickD Removing the `t` gives "Invalid function: (require 'package)".

Comment: `((require 'package)` has too many `(`.  The syntax `(foo ...)` calls a function `foo` passing it arguments `...`.  So `((require 'package) (add-to-list...) ...)` is an attempt to call a function named `(require 'package)`, hence the error message "Invalid function: (require 'package)".

Comment: The moral of the story is that if there is one error, then there are likely more than one :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to how to debug this is to bisect your init file. Comment out 1/2 the lines, then 3/4, 7/8,...

That will narrow down the offending code (e.g., to the sexp that @NickD pointed to in his comment).

@NickD recognized that because he knows what the various sexps in your init file are for - what they're expected to look like. If you don't, then bisecting is a good way to find the needle in the haystack.